# Discover decorated class instance methods in python

Tags: python, reflection, decorator, python-decorators

I have a python class, for example:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    enabled     = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    full_title  = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    alias       = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    author      = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    status      = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    @serializable
    def pretty_status(self):
        return [b for a, b in BOOK_STATUS_CHOICES if a == self.status][0]
```

The method **pretty_status** is decorated with **@serializable**.

What is the simplest and most efficient way to discover the methods in a class that have a certain decoration ? (in the above example giving: pretty_status).

**Edit:**
Please also note that the decorator in question is custom/modifiable.

Comment: Can you modify the decorator, `serializable`?

Comment: yes of course, it's custom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no control over what the decorator does, then in general, you can not identify decorated methods.

However, since you can modify `serializable`, then you could add an attribute to the wrapped function which you could later use to identify serialized methods:

```
import inspect
def serializable(func):
    def wrapper(self):
        pass
    wrapper.serialized = True
    return wrapper

class Book:
    @serializable
    def pretty_status(self):
        pass
    def foo(self):
        pass


for name, member in inspect.getmembers(Book, inspect.ismethod):
    if getattr(member, 'serialized', False):
        print(name, member)
```

yields

```
('pretty_status', <unbound method Book.wrapper>)
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, *you can't*. A decorator is just syntactic sugar for applying a callable. In your case the decorator syntax translates to:

```
def pretty_status(self):
    return [b for a, b in BOOK_STATUS_CHOICES if a == self.status][0]
pretty_status = serializable(pretty_status)
```

That is, `pretty_status` is replaced by whatever `serializable()` returns. What it returns could be anything.

Now, if what `serializable` returns has itself been decorated with [`functools.wraps()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) and you are using Python 3.2 or newer, then you can see if there is a `.__wrapped__` attribute on the new `.pretty_status` method; it's a reference to the original wrapped function.

On earlier versions of Python, you can easily do this yourself too:

```
def serializable(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        # ...

    wrapper.__wrapped__ = func

    return wrapper
```

You can add any number of attributes to that wrapper function, including custom attributes of your own choosing:

```
def serializable(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        # ...

    wrapper._serializable = True

    return wrapper
```

and then test for that attribute:

```
if getattr(method, '_serializable', False):
    print "Method decorated with the @serializable decorator"
```

One last thing you can do is test for that wrapper function; it'll have a `.__name__` attribute that you can test against. That name might not be unique, but it is a start.

In the above sample decorator, the wrapper function is called `wrapper`, so `pretty_status.__name__ == 'wrapper'` will be True.

Answer (score 0):

You can't discover them directly but You can mark decorated methods with some flag.

```
import functools
def serializable(func):
    functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        # ...

    wrapper._serializable = True
    return wrapper
```

And then You can make metaclass for example analyse presence or absence of `_serializable` attribute.

Or You can collect all wrapped methodsin decorator

```
import functools
DECORATED = {}
def serializable(func):
    functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        # ...

    DECORATED[func.__name__] = wrapper
    return wrapper
```